# How I count the words and expressions in a text?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I want to count how much times some given words or phrases appears in a text, but I want use some string similarity algorithms.

Every word or expression has an value, so I will set the relevancy of the text according to the number of words found, etc.

I guess that the `String` class from Java cannot offer this. I will need to iterate all the text for each word or expression I want to find?

Is there a library for text handling?

Example: find texts that has "videogame", "i have a videogame" and something like this, evaluating similar expressions. I guess if I iterate for each word or expression I need to evaluate, I cannot find the similar words and it will be more slower.

Comment: The relevancy is only the first part of an analysis to extract information in the texts, and not to a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want use some String similarity algorithms.

Take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). Allows you to index some text and look for works using a similarity algorithm. I would think you want to split each words and index them using lucene. Then for all the words you are interested for you can search the index. You can do things like `Automobile~` which will do a fuzzy search. Here is a rough algo:

```
for each word in STRING.split(' ')
  index word

for each word in your list
  search for word and look for number of occurrences
```

Comment: If you give me more detail I might be able to help you.

Comment: At the moment, I can rank pages that can contains informations about movies. If certains words or expressions, that page can contains info about movies. If in body, some relevancy, if in keyowrds, another relevancy, if in titles, another, if in URL, another, etc...

Comment: Sounds like this is exactly what you want. I have used lucene in combination with page crawlers to index text. Also recommend using jsoup to parse the html.

Answer (score 1):

The inverted index that Denniss said is what you are looking for. You'll need to define your Document very well if you want a powerfull engine.

**For phrase matches**, your Document should have the position of the word (the key of the Map) in this Document. Once you got all the words you were looking for, you can know if this words were together in the original document.

For example:

```
doc1: "Hello World"
doc2: "Hello Beautiful World"

inverted index {
  "Beautifull": [(doc2, 2)],
  "Hello": [(doc1, 1)(doc2, 1)],
  "World": [(doc1, 2)(doc2, 3)],
}

query: "Hello World"
```

Both documents have the words "Hello" and "World", but doc1 has them together (position 1 and 2) and doc2 doesn't (position 1 and 3).

If you want to find *similar words*, you'll need a new structure. First, you need to define what is similar. [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is what you need for that.

To implement it, you'll need a whole new struture like an automata: [Levenshtein automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton).

Full-text search is a huge area. Implementing a search engine is hard and many libraries and applications already do it.

(I work for Indextank.com a realtime full-text search engine. If you need a search engine running in a couple of minutes, try us out)

Comment: One point, it's not for a search engine. Not at all. It's to page analysis that an robot downloaded. The first analysis of words and phrases will set the relevancy according to the theme I want to retrieve from the texts (at moment, movies) So pages with movie, director, producer, actor has more chances that has content to be extracted than pages without this.

Comment: @Renato: As Leandro said, inverted index is what you're looking for, open source projects such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) will help a lot.

Comment: Hmmm... I've realized that my answer may be wrong according to these comments. I will write another probably more helpful.

Comment: @Leandro Your answer cannot be what I'm searching, but was interesting to learn this and can be helpful in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree with all the guys that suggest you to use Lucene. But, if you have time, it's always funnier to do it your self :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is porbably an Inverted File data structure. I learned this in database class and here is a link to the lecture.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8950924/16Sp11-Search.pdf

Basically the idea is to have a Map data structure

```
Map<String, List<Document>> invertedIndex;
```

where string is the word and `List<Document>` is the documents containing that word.

If you read more into that pdf, you can even find a way to rank the document.