# Java split a string by space, new line, tab, punctuation

Tags: java, string

everyone.

I have a string like this

```
String message = "This is the new message or something like that, OK";
```

And I want to split it into array

```
String[] dic = {"this", "is", "the", "new", "message", "or", "something", "like", "that", "OK"};
```

I used

```
message = message.split("\\s+");
```

The problem was that it contained "that," not "that" like I want. Please teach my how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting strings through regular expressions by punctuation and whitespace etc in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do

```
String[] dic = message.split("\\W+");
```

The `\\W` means not an alphanumeric character.

Comment: Thank you, all! I choose Garrett Hall's answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
 String message = "This is the new message or something like that, OK";
 String delim = " \n\r\t,.;"; //insert here all delimitators
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message,delim);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/):

```
// define splitter as a constant
private static final Splitter SPLITTER =
Splitter.on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.or(CharMatcher.is(','))
        .trimResults()
        .omitEmptyStrings();
// ...

// and now use it in your code
String[] str = Iterables.toArray(SPLITTER.split(yourString), String.class);
```

Comment: Looking at the title, the goal is to remove all punctuation, not just `,`

Comment: @assylias ok, then it would be `Splitter.on(CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.negate()).trimResults().omitEmptyString()`