# Using regex to 'clean up' the string

Tags: java, regex, split

I need a clear text with only words, excluding all digits, extra spaces, dashes, commas, dots, brackets, etc. It is used for a word generation algorithm (taken from gamasutra). I suppose that regular expression can help here. How can I do this with help of String.split?

UPD:

> Input: I have 1337 such a string with different stuff in it: commas,    many spaces, digits - 2 3 4, dashes. How can I remove all stuff?
>
> Output: I have such a string with different stuff in it commas many spaces digits dashes How can I remove all stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting strings through regular expressions by punctuation and whitespace etc in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc)

Comment: Please add an example with input text and expected output text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two steps you could do:

```
String s = "asd asd   asd.asd, asd";
String clean = s.replaceAll("[\\d[^\\w\\s]]+", " ").replaceAll("(\\s{2,})", " ");
System.out.println(clean);
```

The first step removes all characters that are not a letter or a space and replaces them with a space. The second step removes multiple spaces by only one space.

Output:

> asd asd asd asd asd

---

If all you need is an array containing the words, then this would be enough:

```
String[] words = s.trim().split("[\\W\\d]+");
```

Comment: `\w` is also containing digits, the OP wants to remove them also.

Comment: @stema I have amended. Your approach is better anyway (+1).

Answer (score 3):

If you care about Unicode (you should), then use [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

```
String[] result = s.split("\\P{L}+");
```

`\p{L}` is the Unicode property for a letter in any language.

`\P{L}` is the negation of `\p{L}`, means it will match everything that is not a letter. (I understood that is what you want.)

Comment: This perfectly fits in our scenario where we required an accurate length of strings coming from WordPress (via GraphQL). They were showing a different length (`string.length`, usually +1 than the real length) due to the presence of non-Unicode characters and this helped to purge those.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way

```
    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    str = str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}|\\d", "");
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
```

Comment: This will not remove the digits from the text.