# Splitting text by punctuation and special cases like :) or space

Tags: java, regex

I have a following string:

```
Hello word!!!
```

or

```
Hello world:)
```

Now I want to split this string to an array of string which contains Hello,world,!,!,!  or Hello,world,:)

the problem is if there was space between all the parts I could use split(" ")
but here !!! or :) is attached to the string

I also used this code :

```
String Text = "But I know. For example, the word \"can\'t\" should";

String[] Res = Text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
System.out.println(Res.length);
for (String s:Res){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

which I found it from here but not really helpful in my case:
[Splitting strings through regular expressions by punctuation and whitespace etc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have set of characters that should be treated as one piece? Like the smile :) ? Could it be ":x", ":D"? :_(

Comment: Yes I have them in an array

Comment: `\W` matches non word characters, you can combine it with the symbols you have.

Comment: Can you show it in code, I am beginner in working with regx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you do not want to split but rather capture certain groups. The thing with split string is that it gets rid of the parts that you split by (so if you split by spaces, you don't have spaces in your output array), therefore if you split by "!" you won't get them in your output. Possibly this would work for capturing the things that you are interested in:

```
(\w+)|(!)|(:\))/g
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gG7hK8/2)
Mind you don't use string split with it, but rather exec your regex against your string in whatever engine/language you are using. In Java it would be something like:

```
String input = "Hello world!!!:)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\w+)|(!)|(:\))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```

Your matches array will have:

```
["Hello", "world", "!", "!", "!", ":)"]
```

Comment: Perfect just a question in above code where did you split on space because the above code  works well with space as well?

Comment: you don't have to split by spaces, you only "capture" what you are interested in, like capture words, ! or :)

Comment: But between hello and world there is space and I want hello and world separated as well which program perfectly does, so there should be a sign somewhere in your regx which does that

Comment: nope, my regex has 3 groups: (\w) which selects whole words, (!) which selects any single "!", and (:\)) which selects any ":)". I do not split, but I rather say "find me next one". So the loop iterates 6 times, first time it finds "Hello", 2nd is "world" etc... you see the trick now? Any spaces are just skipped :)

Comment: Many likeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees :)