# How do I split a text file in an ArrayList by all type of punctuation?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Alice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*
         * To put the text document into an ArrayList
         */
        Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(new File("ALICES ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (newScanner.hasNext()) {
            list.add(newScanner.next());
        }
        newScanner.close();
    }
}
```

I am stuck on how I can now split the document by all the punctuation, but I still need to be able to perform String operations on the words within the text. Help please

The input is the entire Alice and Wonderland book and I need to output to look like this:

"This book is for the use etc."

Basically where all of the words are separated and all the punctuation is removed from the document.

Comment: What result are you trying to get, and where are you stuck. It should be really straight forward if you take a look at .split() method for strings.

Comment: Basically the output looks like this: [ï»¿project, gutenbergâ€™s, aliceâ€™s, adventures, in, wonderland,, by, lewis, carroll, this, ebook, is, for, the, use, of, anyone, anywhere, at, no, cost, and, with, almost, no, restrictions, whatsoever.,   I need all the commas and periods removed from the arraylist. I know how to do this on a regular array but I cannot figure out how to do it on the arraylist.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the sample input - and please add _expected output_ as well. Also, as Tyler already suggested, have a look at `String.split(regex)` and subsequently on how to match punctuation with regular expressions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc

Comment: "... where all of the words are separated", all words mean to also split on space not only punctuations. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList <> ();
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile ("\\w+");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("ALICES ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = wordPattern.matcher (line);
        while (matcher.find())
            list.add (matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\p{Punct}.` regex' character class as delimiter. The following gives the output below.

### Code

```
String regex = "\\p{Punct}.";
String phrase = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(phrase);
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(regex));

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // <- Try also as much as possible to work with interfaces

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    list.add(scanner.next());
}

list.forEach(System.out::println);
scanner.close();
```

### Result

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry
 standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
It has survived not only five centuries
but also the leap into electronic typesetting
remaining essentially unchanged
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```