# Remove all duplicate words in a sentence using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I’m trying to remove all duplicate words in a sentence using regex but I was only able to remove back to back duplicates and not all the duplicates in the sentence.

Suppose this was the sentence, “I have have a nice have car”

I want it to print “I have a nice car” but it’s printing “I have a nice have car”.

I tried using this regex “\b(\w+)(?:\W+\1\b)+” but this matches 2 or more back to back capturing groups with the second capturing group being one or more non word characters. But I want it to match all the duplicates in the given sentence.

Comment: Why using regular expressions?

Comment: You can't do this with regex. You can if it's word specific but you could end up removing a *same* word where it shouldn't be removed. This is a grammar issue and would require a library to handle such cases. Perhaps use **ANTLR** to create a specific parser for this sort of thing or find an API that is already created to suit your needs.

Comment: This might not be used in real time but I would still like to find out if there is a solution through regex. There are multiple ways to solve this but I’m looking for regex answer only.

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex that is performed only once?  I can easily see this being done as a single regex replacement in a while loop.

Comment: With [a little workaround it could work (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/5hkgvb/1), but this is limited and very ugly to use :p

Comment: Could you explain this “ (?i)\b(\w+)\b(?<=\b(?=\1\b).{1,999}\W{1,9}\w{1,99})\W*” @bobblebubble

Comment: @Prickachu It's working around limitations of Java Regex which only allows a limited width inside a lookbehind and not such as `.*`. The other workaround is because no backreference alowed in a lookbehind such as `(?<=\1)`. That's why I used a look*ahead* inside the lookbehind. Simpler in JS e.g. [`\b(\w+)\b(?<=\b\1\b.+)\W*`](https://regex101.com/r/xGIKca/1). The `999` is just any value I picked for the max length that your input could have, `99` word length and `9` for characters between words. Adjust to your needs if not sufficient. Hope that helped a bit. More explanation in Regex101 demos.

Comment: One way or another, this will always lead to broken sentences in certain cases, like: "we do not know if we have talked, or not" -> "We do not know if have talked, or"?!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting the sentence into words and then adding the words to a `LinkedHashSet` which maintains order of added elements. Hence it will keep the first occurrence of a word and disregard all subsequent occurrences.

Splitting into words can be achieved with the regular expression: `\P{L}+`
(which I found in the [accepted] answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384791/splitting-strings-through-regular-expressions-by-punctuation-and-whitespace-etc) SO question)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RmDupWrd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "I have have a nice have car.";
        String[] words = s.split("\\P{L}+");
        Arrays.stream(words)
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new LinkedHashSet<>()))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
I
have
a
nice
car
```

Comment: I’m actually looking for a solution through regex only

Answer (score 0):

The details of the above regular expression are:

“\b”: A word boundary. Boundaries are needed for special cases. For example, in “My thesis is great”, “is” won't be matched twice.

“\w+” A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

“\W+”: A non-word character: [^\w]

“\1”: Matches whatever was matched in the 1st group of parentheses, which in this case is the (\w+)

“+”: Match whatever it’s placed after 1 or more times

So for your case, you need to update the regex as

```
final String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\b\\s*(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)";
final String input = "Goodbye bye bye world world world\n";

final String result = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/6)

Comment: This doesn’t do what OP wants.

Comment: This gives me the same result as the one I used. Not helping.